# Error with Tableau Linux install: No such file or directory [**/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/docs.<version>/EULA.rtf**]

Tags: linux

I was installing Tableau Server 10.5. I've installed Tableau Server 10.5 successfully on my Linux box. But when I was running the following script to start TSM: **sudo ./initialize-tsm --accepteula**, I got an error -

**Enabling and starting all services

Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory**

I didn't get "ELUA.rtf" at given location. Please suggest how can I get this at below location -
**/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/docs./EULA.rtf**

Answer (score 0):

That path contains a 'place holder' for the actual version of the server.

The actual path is something like this: `/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/docs.10500.18.0109.1050/EULA.rtf`